# template function call with empty angle brackets <>

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

I am confused with the below template behavior, where it compiles fine with the empty angle brackets (template without parameters) since syntactically, template<> is reserved to mark an explicit template specialization.

```
template <typename T> void add(T a, T b) { }
int main() {
    add<>(10, 3); // compiles fine since both parameters are of same data type
    add<>(10, 3.2); // Error: no matching function for call to add(int, double)
}
```

In the above case is the template parameter really optional?

Answer (score 12):

> `template<>` is reserved to mark an explicit template specialization.

It means various things, depending on context. Here it means "use the default or deduced argument", just as if you simply said `add`.

In the first case, both function arguments have the same type, so the template argument can be deduced as `int`.

In the second case, they have different types, so the template argument can't be deduced. You'd have to specify what you want, e.g. `add<double>`, convert one function argument to match the other, or modify the template to parametrise each type separately.

> In the above case is the template parameter really optional?

Yes, if it can be deduced from the argument types.

Answer (score 6):

In the first case, *yes* because the can be inferred through the standard's rules.  In the second, *no* because they can't - you'd have to write something like:

```
add<float>(10, 3.2);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a single template parameter and two function parameters of different types. Template argument deduction needs to match for both arguments, but if you supply an int and a double, it doesn't work. The reason is that deduced argument have to an exact match and **type conversions** are not considered.

The syntax

```
add<double>(10, 3.2);
```

would explicitly force `T` to be equal to `double`. In that case, the `int` constant `10` is converted to `double`.

You could also add another overload

```
template <typename T, typename U> void add(T a, U b) { }
```

and possibly constrain that using SFINAE by requiring that `is_convertible<T, U>`